# Pine script: ta.lowestbars() returning wrong value for certain bars when called through request.security()

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, trading, algorithmic-trading

I am using ta.lowestbars() inside a function thats being called using request.security().

**ta.lowestbars()** returns 0 for certain bars even though the current bar low isnt the lowest. I have clearly shown the same in the attached images. Can someone point out what I am missing here.

> [EXAMPLE WITH ECICHERMOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppHLc.png)
> [EXAMPLE WITH COALINDIA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7oXn.png)

I am expecting it to give the correct bar length from the current bar which is having the lowest low within the given days.